# How can I merge two data without losing date both of them

Tags: python, pandas

all
Could you please help me with merging data, I try to merge data1 and data2 by typing this code: "merged3= pd.merge(left = merged2 ,
right = user, how='outer',on=['user_id']).fillna(0)" . But the problem is month1 in data1 disapper. How can I keep month1 column after merging data1 with data2 .
You can see the result in data3 picture.
Thanks in advance:[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you may  try `pandas.concat`. 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need you reset your index for merge2 df and then merge again,

```
merged2 = merged2.reset_index()
merged3= pd.merge(left = merged2 , right = user, how='outer',on=['user_id']).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Month 1 is part of the [multi-index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) with `user_id`, when you merge on only the `user_id` level of the multi-index you throw away the `month`.

To get the behaviour I think you want, you need to do the following:

```
merged2 = merged2.reset_index(['month'])

merged3 = pd.merge(left = merged2 , right = user, how='outer',on=['user_id']).fillna(0)
```

`merged2.reset_index(['month'])` basically turns the `month` level of your multi-index into a column.